# Sprite texture compression in Unity

Tags: performance, unity-game-engine, compression, sprite

I wish to compress my `png sprite textures` a bit so they don't take up that much memory as I build for mobile devices. As I use a lot of gif animations this is crucial for my game's performance. 
I looked for an answer but the threads I found were more than 1 year old and not about `sprites` so I figured I ask my version. An image that's 224 KB in size takes up 1.6 MB in Unity with the `generate mip maps` turned **off**
So compressing the `png sprite textures` in my game. How to do that?

Comment: generate mip maps  is not a compression. and do you wish to compress texture ? look at lowest panel when you click texture, you can choose texture compression type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting **Format** to **Automatic Compressed**.

For this to work on all mobile platforms make sure the initial image has sizes that are power of 2 (actually I think that multiple of 4 should be enough, but just to be on the safe side).

This will lower the quality of the image but should save you some space.

Turning mip map off is again a good idea as mim map increase the size of the image by about 33%.

And one more thing, make sure that **Non Power of 2** is set to **None**, that may be the reason you see an increase in size at the moment.

Comment: Thanks for the help. 
For one sprite sheet I can resize my textures easily (in the main menu) but the textures in my levels - there are a lot of them, all of them cropped to the minimal size and none of them are a power of 2 or a multiple of 4 :/ any quick way to do that or shall I just turn off mip maps and hope for the best?
The severe mem usage is in the main menu of course because of the long sprite sheet.

Comment: for UI you should turn off mip maps anyway, as mipmaps will make them blurry. You should try to use atlases as much as possible and one way of making them power of two is to simply add transparent space to the atlas in an image editor.

Comment: [Radu Dita](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2054602/radu-dita) I turned off mip maps in all my textures, it helped a lot. I re-rendered the main menu to be a power of 2, this halfed the overall memory size :D 
However, my other (enormous amount) sprites I do not have the means to crop them manually using my 2d app.
Could this work using the atlas method you mentioned?
If so, would it change their position in the game? (2d solely, lotta sprites)
Finally, if I mess things up, how to revert? 
Thanks in advance.